# Weird file named Ya gets created every startup- I think related to visual studio... What is it and How do I stop this from happening?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, wix

Essentially, the title of the post but to be more specific here's an overview of what happens.

Every time I start my computer, after I log in a file that windows does not know what to use to open gets created-- it pops up the "open this file with" select program dialog. The file is called "Ya".

This file contains the text in the code block or very similar every time. (in the code block i've redacted stuff that looks like it may be registration keys in case that's what they are)

If I open the file in Visual Studio or Atom or any text editor it just shows what looks like is a log file.

I have no idea what it is, but I'm assuming it's visual studio / visual studio code related because it contains a bunch of stuff called like VC_redist.x64.exe

So firstly... does anyone have any idea what this might be, what process is creating it, and how do I either prevent that process from running or at least stop it from showing me this file on boot? It's annoying and a little unnerving.

```
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i001: Burn v3.10.4.4718, Windows v10.0 (Build 19042: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Windows\Temp\{7EEEFA05-8FB6-4274-9370-9EDFE00658CF}\.cr\VC_redist.x64.exe
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.31.31103,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=540 -burn.filehandle.self=536 /q /norestart /log C:\Users\Ya Boy Andwee\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220216165950_443_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.31.31103,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.31.31103,chip=x64\'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Ya'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.31.31103'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[0E0C:2BDC][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '14.31.31103.0'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i100: Detect begin, 11 packages
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'Arm64_Check' to value 'AMD64'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting version variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKey' to value '10.0.19041.789'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 1
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i102: Detected related bundle: {{{{redacted}}}}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.29.30135.0, operation: MajorUpgrade
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i103: Detected related package: {{{{{also redacted}}}}}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.29.30135.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i103: Detected related package: {{{{{also redacted}}}}}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.29.30135.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i103: Detected related package: {{{{{also redacted}}}}}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.29.30135.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i103: Detected related package: {{{{{also redacted}}}}}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.29.30135.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i101: Detected package: vcRuntime_arm64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.1' evaluates to true.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i200: Plan begin, 11 packages, action: Install
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64) AND NOT (Arm64_Check = "ARM64")' evaluates to true.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Ya_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Ya_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64) AND NOT (Arm64_Check = "ARM64")' evaluates to true.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Ya_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Ya_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i052: Condition 'Arm64_Check = "ARM64"' evaluates to false.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i201: Planned package: vcRuntime_arm64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i207: Planned related bundle: {fa7f6d52-f85e-48ef-8f56-a37268aa5772}, type: Upgrade, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, dependency: None
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i300: Apply begin
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:04]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:24]i361: Created a system restore point.
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:24]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Windows\Temp\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.31,bundle, version: 14.31.31103.0
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2E94:475C][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}v14.31.31103\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[2E94:475C][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i305: Verified acquired payload: {{{{also redacted}}}}at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\{{{{also redacted}}}}, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}v14.31.31103\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[2E94:475C][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}v14.31.31103\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[2E94:475C][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}v14.31.31103\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:25]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}v14.31.31103\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:36]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: Required
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:36]i325: Registering dependency: {2aaf1df0-eb13-4099-9992-962bb4e596d1} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:36]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}v14.31.31103\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i325: Registering dependency: {2aaf1df0-eb13-4099-9992-962bb4e596d1} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i301: Applying execute package: {fa7f6d52-f85e-48ef-8f56-a37268aa5772}, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{fa7f6d52-f85e-48ef-8f56-a37268aa5772}\VC_redist.x64.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{fa7f6d52-f85e-48ef-8f56-a37268aa5772}\VC_redist.x64.exe" -uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.ancestors={2aaf1df0-eb13-4099-9992-962bb4e596d1} -burn.filehandle.self=1228'
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i319: Applied execute package: {fa7f6d52-f85e-48ef-8f56-a37268aa5772}, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}, resume: ARP, restart: Required, disable resume: No
[2E94:08FC][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{{{{also redacted}}}}}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: Required, ba requested restart:  No
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0xbc2
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: Arm64_Check = AMD64
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: SystemFolder = C:\Windows\system32\
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: VersionNT = 10.0.0.0
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: VersionNT64 = 10.0.0.0
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: windows_uCRT_DetectKey = 10.0.19041.789
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists = 1
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 14.31.31103.0
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\Ya
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 = C:\Users\Ya_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 = C:\Users\Ya_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.31.31103
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.31.31103,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.31.31103,chip=x64\
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.31,bundle
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 = C:\Users\Ya_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 = C:\Users\Ya_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.31.31103,chip=x64\
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.31.31103,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 14.31.31103.0
[0E0C:4AB4][2022-02-16T17:04:37]i007: Exit code: 0xbc2, restarting: No
```

Comment: `C:\Users\Ya Boy Andwee\AppData\...` might explain the Ya

Comment: Looks like it is checking to see if a MSVC redistributable needs to be installed. Just as puzzled as you are, unfortunately.

Comment: `Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Ya'` ... it looks like the installer was not made to account for spaces in the path ... That's a bad installer... or whomever is launching the installer is using bad parameters

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using the following command-line to install the VC Redist bundle:

```
VC_redist.x64.exe /q /norestart /log C:\Users\Ya Boy Andwee\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220216165950_443_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log
```

Notice that the parameter to the the `-log` switch is not quoted. Therefore, a log file is being created with the name `C:\Users\Ya` (with no file extension) and the following are also passed as parameters to the VC redist and probably ignored:

1. `Boy`
2. `Andwee\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220216165950_443_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log`

Try the following command-line instead (note the quotes):

```
VC_redist.x64.exe /q /norestart /log "C:\Users\Ya Boy Andwee\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220216165950_443_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this question today after I had the same problem. Here is, how I fixed it (Windows 10):

Open the Starte Menu and type "Apps and Features" and open the correspondings settings.

Here you can see a list of all installed applications. Search for something along "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable "
You may want to sort the the list by Installation Date to find it quicker. Installation Date should be the date since the problem is occuring.

Find and click the correct entry and select Uninstall. Do not worry, I'll include a link where you can reinstall these apps below.

In my case I also uninstalled the x86 Version of this App, as it got installed on the same day. Although I'm not sure if this is neccessary, as I could only locate hints to x64 within the log files. You might want to give it a try aswell.

After this go to your Users-Folder. This is typically located at "C:\Users"
Here you'll find the file which is opened upon startup and which might brought you to this page. It should be named after the first name of your user profile, without any filetype extension. So let's say your Username is "Jane Doe", in this case the file is simply called "Jane"

Delete the file (or move it to somewhere in case you want to restore it) and restart your PC.

In my case thise solved the issue.

After this I went to https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=26999 to reinstall both packages.

In case the link does not work anymore just google for "C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable" and you should find it on Microsofts official Webpage.

Comment: This is overkill dude. Just delete that file in your users folder, the one without the extension and all should be fine. You might also notice the other log files dumped there by the same application.

Comment: Simply deleting the file did not solve the problem for me as it was recreated on every startup.

Comment: [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21399290/daniel) try to also visit your registry and add quotation marks to the entry that is associated with this behavior. This will atleast ensure it is recreated into the right folder because if you are following, it is not a harmful file, and the application generating it is attempting to find the right location... a system location to create it. But your user name has spaces in it in. Thus it stops reading the file path where the space begins.

Comment: I am fully aware that problem was caused by incorrect quotation marks during the installation of the C++ package and I never assumed the file was harmful in any way, but as you can see I have chosen a different way to solve the issue. However as the problem does not occur anymore on my side I see no reason to tinker with the registry.

Comment: Yes, the registry is best left alone unless you know what you are doing because errors there can be irrecoverable.

Answer (score 1):

This is [the best solution](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/open-with-dialog-appears-login/?expand_article=1) that I found, though simply deleting the file will also help solve the issue in the short-term. I am unsure if the PC regenerates it down the line.

But most importantly, you may need log files later on down the line working with your machine. The file just seems like an incorrectly named log file. It is harmless to your machine, but the unexpected startup behavior may be worrying.